# WP All Import don't importing values from custom fields

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have custom tab for Frequently Bought Together products in my woocommerce site, that shows up on single product page. When i update products via WP All Import, only one product show up in custom tab and should be a two. Here is the settings of custom fields import and actually view of the single product page.

[custom-fields-settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zxFvZ.jpg)

[single-product-accessory-tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XLSE5.jpg)

I'll provide Single Product Accessories template, just to make it clear

[accessorie template function](https://pastebin.com/cmXEkzWd)

```
global $product;
 
$loop_columns = apply_filters( 'mc_accessories_loop_columns', 4 );
$posts_per_page = 4;
 
if ( defined( 'WC_VERSION' ) && version_compare( WC_VERSION, '3.3', '<' ) ) {
    global $woocommerce_loop;
    $woocommerce_loop['columns'] = $loop_columns;
} else {
    wc_set_loop_prop( 'columns', $loop_columns );
}
 
$product_id = mc_wc_get_product_id( $product );
$accessories = MediaCenter_WC_Helper::get_accessories( $product );
array_unshift( $accessories, $product_id );
 
if ( sizeof( $accessories ) === 0 && !array_filter( $accessories ) ) {
    return;
}
 
$meta_query = WC()->query->get_meta_query();
 
$args = apply_filters( 'mc_accessories_query_args', array(
    'post_type'           => 'product',
    'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1,
    'no_found_rows'       => 1,
    'posts_per_page'      => $posts_per_page,
    'orderby'             => 'post__in',
    'post__in'            => $accessories,
    'meta_query'          => $meta_query
) );
 
unset( $args['meta_query'] );
 
$products = new WP_Query( $args );
 
$add_to_cart_checkbox   = '';
$total_price            = 0;
$count                  = 0;
```

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Solution is so easy, just need to import post Id's, i lost two weeks on that problem.